# Deleted everything from pc

Tags: windows-7, kali-linux, mbr

Recently I decided to install Kali linux on my device by replacing windows completely, I made a bootable kali pendrive and started the installation process, since I didn't want Windows, I chose to completely wipe it and use kali, but then the internet connection gave up on me and kali installation failed.

The problem now is that for few weeks I have no access to the internet (currently using mobile data) and when I power up my system (without the bootable pendrive), I'm greeted with a blank screen, and I just see an underscore (_) blinking in the top left corner.

I guess, I deleted windows and MBR, what to do now?

P.S.: Is there any way to install Kali without internet connection?

Comment: -1 your title "Deleted everything from pc" isn't even a question..  and then you ask "what to do now?"   I don't know what you want to do. You can go to the movies if you want.  You ask "P.S.: Is there any way to install Kali without internet connection?"  You can install any OS without an internet connection. If there is an exception then it'd 
 be an interest exception, but why don't you try?

Comment: you write "I have no access to the internet (currently using mobile data) "   So you do have access to the internet.  Is there a problem that you can't connect your router to your Home ISP.

Comment: Though I've answered, @barlop is correct in pointing out that you should improve the quality of your question to benefit others who may eventually see it. Start with the title.

Comment: Your attempt to replace Windows with Kali Linux makes my suspect that maybe, *just maybe* you want to use Kali as your desktop OS. If so, [don't](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399627/108618).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yeah it's kind of like a person being a celebrity along with being a pedophile

Answer (score 3):

There are many Linux distro installers that include all required data in the install media (though you'll need the internet to get them).

> - Download a "complete" installation .iso of the distro of choice
> - Create install media with rufus, Universal USB installer, or equivalent
> - Boot from installation media and continue install as you did previously.

Now, if you have absolutely no internet connection available to download the installation image, there are plenty of services that sell premade installation media (CD/DVD/USB/Etc). This method is definitely not preferred for various reasons (cost, scam, security).

Answer (score -2):

If you have a bootable pen drive, might I suggest booting into kali temporarily. You should also be able to install without updating. Then just update once you are up and running the OS.
Also, if you didn't delete the restore partition, you can reinstall windows and then try again.

Comment: Windows can be reinstalled anytime with or without the *recovery* partition. And the part of your answer that's correct merely repeats what the other answer says. Please avoid doing that. If you agree with an answer consider upvoting it and if you have nothing to add then please don't.